# Updating .PHTML Template Files Not Displaying Changes On Site

Tags: php, templates, magento, magento-1.9

I am attempting to make a minor edit to the list.phtml file in a custom theme for a Magento 1.9 site. Unfortunately even after turning on template-path hints, clearing and then disabling the caches I am not seeing my changes reflected on the site.

I have checked out Google and Stack Overflow for other people's encounters with this issue. I've toggled the template-path-hints to verify that I am indeed editing the correct file.

Essentially all I want to do is remove the "Read More" link from the template.

According to the template path hints the phtml file that I am looking to edit is at *frontend/mycustomPackage/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml*

I edited the file on the server at that location and expected the changes to be reflected on the product catalog list page, but they haven't shown up. I have been spinning my cubic wheels on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the following:
 1. Have you tried changing the theme?
 2. Try by creating a child theme of default to chek the changes.
 3. It can be a memcache issue also
 4. Make sure that the read more link is from that list.phtml. Sometimes,it shows the file but the data is retrieved either from block or module.

If these are not useful,you can share the Project details to my email-id.I will fix it for you.

Please vote if you find these links helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it turned to be a memcache issue!

Answer (score 0):

If any third party caching is using then try to clear the cache from console.

Comment: Thank you it turned out to be a memcache issue.